# I used WMIC and I got error: RPC server is unavailable

Tags: windows, command, wmi

I would like to use WMIC and get products information about all PCs.
So I tried:

```
wmic /node:"IPAddress" /user:"domain\administrator" /password "Password" /output:c:\test.txt product get name, vendor
```

It does not work with all PCs.
I got error: `Description = RPC server is unavailable.`

Is there any idea to solve this problem??
And the service is running (Remote Procedure Call)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you `ping IPAddress` successfully?

Comment: yess it is currently running IP address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probable reason:

- Firewall configuration (RPC connections blockage)
- You don't enough permission to run WMI queries.
- Machine is not reachable. Try pinging the machine.

Second point is valid if you are trying to run queries on remote machines. You can use `wbemtest` to verify.

- Windows+R (run command)
- Type wbemtest
- Once UI is opened, try to connect to the machine which is throwing exception.

Comment: Even when using /user and /password switches for wmic with domain admin credentials, you may still experience this issue if you are not logged in as a domain admin on the machine where you execute the remote command.